# General position for one-parameter family of algebraic numbers

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra

Let $P(x,y)$ be an irreducible twovariate polynomial with rational coefficients
such that $P(n,.)$ has degree $>1$ for any $n\in{\mathbb N}$.

For any $n\in{\mathbb N}$, one may choose a root $\alpha_n\in{\mathbb C}$
of $P(n,.)$.

I say that a finite set of integers $n_1<n_2< \ldots <n_r$ is in general
position if the set of extensions ${\mathbb Q}(\alpha_{n_1}),{\mathbb Q}(\alpha_{n_2}),
\ldots , {\mathbb Q}(\alpha_{n_r})$ is linearly disjoint over $\mathbb Q$,
for any choice of the $\alpha_i$.

Which polynomials have arbitrarily large sets in general position ?

An easy example is $P(x,y)=y^2-x$ ; the $\sqrt{p}$ ($p$ prime) are linearly disjoint over $\mathbb Q$.